# Take out the item out of container relatively from chat like design

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have tried creating this message
[image: outside heart]
UI similar to instagram but I failed for relative heart shape, I need to bind the heart with the container itself but it doesn't seems to work as a result output is
[image: sharing same border]

The code I tried is

.html

```
<div class="recieved">anohter left <i class="fa fa-heart heart-reaction"></i>  </div>
```

.css

```
 .recieved {
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    width: fit-content;
   padding-right:1rem
  }
 .heart-reaction{
      color: red;
  }
```

I am using font awesome icons here,

> I tried adding outside as well but It seems not right for sending the message as it goes at the recievers end

Comment: Do you need the heart outside of the container on the left side

Comment: yes, similar to instagram

Comment: Try the code that I sent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 .recieved {
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
    width: fit-content;
    position:relative;
    
  }
 .heart-reaction{
      color: red;
      position:absolute;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      height:20px;
      width:20px;
      border-radius:50%;
      background:orange;
  }
```

```css
.recieved {
        flex-direction: row;
        padding: 12px;
        border-radius: 40px;
        margin: 2px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: grey;
        width: fit-content;
        position:relative;
       padding-right:2rem;
      }
     .heart-reaction{
          color: red;
          position:absolute;
          right:rem;
          bottom:0rem;
         height:20px;
         width:20px;
         border-radius:50%;
         background:orange;
      }
```

```html
<div class="recieved">anohter left <span class="fa fa-heart heart-reaction">i</span>  </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, The heart goes at the left bottom of the page

Comment: Where do you want it... Just run the code snippet above ... You simply need to use left, right, bottom and top properties to place it at the desired position

Comment: Welcome. Do please accept the answer and vote that will help other's as well :)

Comment: the heart is overlapped with the next message ?? Any idea how to resolved that

Comment: Can you share your code my friend. Share on codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226524/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-piyush-dubey).

Answer (score 2):

If you set the position of the div as relative, and then set the position of the icon as absolute, you can adjust the location of your icon easily.

https://jsfiddle.net/z3gyosfd/

```
.recieved {
  position:relative;
 }

.heart-reaction{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
 }
```